# App Thinning - example for Bitcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, bitcode, app-thinning

iOS 9 has introduced App Thinning in three ways:

1. App Slicing
2. Resource On Demand
3. Bit Code: sort of plug-in for iOS App

I can see tutorial as well as example code for **1.** and **2.**, but I can't find details for Bitcode.

Comment: I wrote an article that aims to explain what the Bitcode is, you can find it here: http://lowlevelbits.org/bitcode-demystified/

Comment: @shesh nath can you please send me the links for 1 and 2? I didn't find any examples to implement it in code

Comment: @SRI - this post is quite old, now i can't remember/access examples, please google it

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2) on this (quite short compared to the other two):

> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.

Citing [Arstechnica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/06/app-thinning-will-be-a-major-boon-for-8gb-and-16gb-iphones-and-ipads/) for further explanation:

> The final piece of the puzzle is something Apple calls "Bitcode." When developers upload apps to the App Store, they'll no longer be submitting pre-compiled binaries, but an "intermediate representation" of those apps that is compiled on demand depending on the device you're downloading it to. This enables some of the App Slicing functionality—it determines whether your device downloads a 32-bit or 64-bit binary.

and it is activated by `ENABLE_BITCODE` in `Project > Build Settings > Build Options > Enable bitcode`.

Comment: In which sense? Were you not able to activate it? Or you don't understand it? The activation is pretty straight forward.

Comment: this point:- "Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the App Store." , here bitcode means what just enabled bitcode in build setting or code of, swift or objective-c

Comment: Indeed that is correct. Bitcode is not a plug-in as you are asking in your question. It is submitting you app one step before compilation - so depending on the device, the app will be compiled for 32 or 64 bit architecture.